# Execute script inside Docker Swarm node from Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-swarm

I have a Django application that is deployed to Docker Swarm. (Replicated, running on several nodes)

The application contains some shell script `do_stuff.sh` that has to be executed periodically, which eventually ends up with executing the custom command `python manage.py do_django_stuff` on the node.

What I want is to schedule and trigger the execution of the script from Jenkins. (As from there it is convenient to track the results/see log output for troubleshooting etc)

The application has fixed FQDN (e.g. `my_app.my_server.com`) but I am struggling with how to point from Jenkins to the specific container to execute the script there.

How can I achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want Jenkins to trigger it? Could you not add the script to the containers (and image build time) and trigger them via a cron schedule? Remotely triggering scripts sounds like an anti-pattern.

Comment: @JohnXF let's say it's a kind of legacy. Currently, the job is triggered by Jenkins and the application is not dockerized. Thus, the idea is to have as few as possible changes during the transition to Docker. Additionally, Jenkins is more transparent - much easier to parametrize and then analyze in console output.
Actually, I've figured out how to do this. When done - will post an update to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. To do the task above - I had to do two things:

- Put label on Jenkins job that targets build to the Docker Swarm cluster (picks up one of the machines)
- execute the script as `docker exec $(docker ps -q -f name=name_of_my_application) ./do_stuff.sh`

So I achieve the behaviour when the task is executed inside Docker Swarm but has the same output as it would be on a regular deployment